# Cookies are not Accessible in the Office Outlook AddIn

Tags: cookies, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Addin for outlook, following is my issue
**problem statement:**
IE & Safari by default third party cookies are disabled, I am not able to set the cookies of my application because it is treated as third party, so I am launching the model dialog to show my Application login page, after successful login, I see cookie is set and I am closing my model dialog window. after that I am refreshing my host page to redirect to the portal which we designed for Addin, here my Addin is not able to read the cookie. but when I open the new tab, I am able to access my portal because cookie is available

I have work around i.e. enable third party cookies in the browser, but I don't want to ask  my customers to enable the browser third party cookies. hence I tried to set the cookie through model dialog.

Thanks for your help, I am excited to know why I am not able to access the cookie available in my browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

For user authentication Office.js provides [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialog?view=word-js-preview). The Dialog features especially designed to provide seamless user experience across of different clients and platform. This API is fully supported by Outlook, subject to [Dialog API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets). `Office.context.ui`, provides objects and methods that you can use to create and manipulate UI components, such as dialog boxes, in your Office Add-in.

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: @NadavB Thanks, fixed.